# Keyboard backlight on Asus laptop

Tags: drivers, shortcut-keys, asus, backlight

I'm unable to turn off backlight of my keyboard. I've tried every solutions available on the internet including **xset**, etc. But nothing seem to work on AsusFX503. I've Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Please help.

Comment: Try `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness`

Comment: tee: '/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness': No such file or directory
0

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /sys/class/leds/`?

Comment: @Kulfy sorry for late reply.
[output](https://pastebin.com/emZMJ39w)

Comment: And what about `ls -l /sys/devices/platform`?

Comment: [Output](https://pastebin.com/9PBc90Pu) @Kulfy

Comment: And what about `ls -l /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/`?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/': No such file or directory

Comment: Strange. What about `ls -l /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/`?

Comment: [Output](https://pastebin.com/dyexNxZr)

Comment: The folder should be there. I'm not sure why it's happening. I don't own Asus laptop so can't dig more. Hope someone else could help you.

Comment: Let's hope so. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I am also having this problem on my G531GT - asus::kbd_backlight is not present anywhere on the system.

Comment: @mkreisel did you find any solution?

Comment: as you didnt mention what xset command you used, did you try this one    xset led off

Comment: @pierrely yes. I used xset led off. Didn't work for me.

Comment: that was just a usbkeyboard though. quick search here  if new to you https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_backlight using upower and python-bus                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980027/asus-laptop-fx503-keyboard-backlight-control-not-work-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in kernel 5.0, check `xev` and try to press this combos.

Comment: nothing happening. The data updates but not when I press "fn + arrow_down", which is how keyboard backlight can be changed. Thank You..

Comment: What kernel version do you have? Run `uname -a`, and what kind of data are you talking about?
Since kernel 5.0+ fn+arrow combos should map to XF86KbdBrightnessUp and down

Comment: Yea! Thanks. I upgraded to kernel 5 from 4. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the `rogauracore` package on Github here: https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore. On my G531GT it allowed me to control the color of the backlight, which included turning it off. I can't easily dim the backlight, but I can choose a color which is less bright, effectively dimming it, although not as convenient.

It's not the real solution to the problem (which probably involves some kernel update), but a very useful workaround with the added bonus that you can actually control the RGB on the backlight too.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work from me. which colour did you use? I've red backlight, tried some dim hex values but didn't work :).

Comment: Does `rogauracore black` work for you? My keyboard is RGB so it makes a bit more sense to control the color. Sorry if it didn't work for you :(

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks